# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Hi I am trying to insert data into db but it says:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `projects` (`owner_id`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (1, 2019-06-28 13:17:11, 2019-06-28 13:17:11))

I am following [Laracasts Laravel from scratch tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/30?autoplay=true)

controller:

```
      public function store()
      {
        $attributes = $this->validateProject();
        $attributes['owner_id'] = auth()->id();
        $project = Project::create($attributes);

    //Project::create($attributes);
    //Project::create(request(['title', 'description']));

          Mail::to($project->owner->email)->send(
            new ProjectCreated($project)
          );

        return redirect('/projects');
      }
```

model:

```
  protected $guarded = [];
```

table:

```
      Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('owner_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

blade file:

```
   <form method="POST" action="/projects">
   @csrf
   <div class="field">
    <label class="label" for="title">Title</label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" class="input {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'is-danger' : ''}}" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}" placeholder="Project title">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label class="label" for="title">Description</label>
      <div class="control">
        <textarea name="description" class="textarea {{ $errors->has('description') ? 'is-danger' : ''}}" placeholder="Project description">{{ old('description') }}</textarea>
    </div>
   </div>
      <div class="field">
      <div class="control">
        <button type="submit" class="button is-link">Create Project</button>
        </div>
    </div>

   @include('errors')

  </form>
```

how to solve this issue

Comment: Can you please add your validateProject() function?

Comment: i add a new function at bottom here is complete controller paste.ofcode.org/htHYYDkYnKhgux6azDKtVh –

Comment: What do you get when you `dd($request->all());` inside Controller store function?

Comment: nthing same error

Comment: In the first opening line of the store function of the store function.

Comment: https://ibb.co/zPR3w0R

Answer (score 7):

You have the field `title` on the `projects` table however you are not assigning it a value. As it is set as `Not Nullable` this will give this error.

You will need all attributes to be in the `$fillable` attribute on the model when using `Project::create($attributes);` which you do not seem to have.

An example of the `$fillable` would be :

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'description',
    'owner_id',
];
```

There are several other potential causes however it is impossible to tell without you including your full `Project` model and the view which this request is from.

**Edit**

You will need to change your function to this :

```
public function store(ProjectRequest $request)
  {
    $attributes = $request->all();
    $attributes['owner_id'] = auth()->id();
    $project = Project::create($attributes);

      Mail::to($project->owner->email)->send(
        new ProjectCreated($project)
      );

    return redirect('/projects');
  }
```

You can create the `ProjectRequest` class by running `php artisan make:request ProjectRequest` and then putting your validation rules in there instead.

Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests).

Comment: @programmer0001 what is the table structure and what are you passing in your request?

Comment: @programmer0001 I have updated my answer with the correct `$fillable`. See if that works?

Comment: no ssame error m following the laracasts series   laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/30?autoplay=true

Comment: @programmer0001 what is the `$this->validateProject();` function?

Comment: i add a new function at bottom here is complete controller    paste.ofcode.org/htHYYDkYnKhgux6azDKtVh

Answer (score 2):

Add your column name in `fillable` like this in your model (I guess your model name is `Project.php`)

So your model class should like this.

```
<?php

mnamespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
protected $guarded = [];
protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'owner_id','description'
];
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}

public function addTask($task)
{
    $this->tasks()->create($task);
}
}
```

And then update your `controller` `store` method like this.

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $attributes = $this->validateProject();
    $attributes->owner_id = auth()->id();
    $attributes->title = $this->request->title;
    $attributes->description= $this->request->description;
    $project = Project::create($attributes);

      Mail::to($project->owner->email)->send(
        new ProjectCreated($project)
      );

    return redirect('/projects');
  }
```

Comment: Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController::$request

Comment: do you have this line `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your controller after `namespace`  ?

Comment: yes   complete controller:    paste.ofcode.org/htHYYDkYnKhgux6azDKtVh

Comment: Please use my updated `store` method. I have updated the code in `store` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195700/discussion-between-fokrule-and-programmer0001).

Comment: Creating default object from empty value   this error is at this line  $attributes->owner_id = auth()->id();

Comment: add this line `$attributes = new Project;` before `$attributes->owner_id = auth()->id();` this line

Comment: Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController::$request

Answer (score 1):

The error itself is self explanatory, check this code:

```
$attributes['owner_id'] = auth()->id();
$project = Project::create($attributes);
```

here you are creating a new record in project table, and for that you are taking only one column i.e. `owner_id`, but in the table there is a column `title` which do not have a default value. 
So either take all the column while creating a new record or provide those column a default value (null or something else).

To set `null` as default value in migration:

```
$table->string('title')->nullable();
```

or you can directly change the column in database and set its default value as null, see the below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: m new to laravel and first time following the laracasts series can u plz show me code about what should i do

Answer (score 0):

Unable to trace the problem you are facing. Give this code a try and please comment if you got any problem.

Inside your route file

```
Route::post('project', 'ProjectController@store')->name('project.store');
```

In your create view

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('project.store')}}">
    @csrf
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label" for="title">Title</label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" class="input {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'is-danger' : ''}}" name="title"
                   value="{{ old('title') }}" placeholder="Project title">
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <button type="submit" class="button is-link">Create Project</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    @include('errors')

</form>
```

In your ProjectController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class UserController extends Controller{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);

        $post = Post::create([
                    'title' => $request->title,
                    'owner_id' => auth()->id()
                    ]);

    return redirect('/projects');
  }
```

EDIT 1

In your previous code inside ProjectsController, instead of using $attributes try using

```
public function store()
    {
        $project = Project::create([
            'title' => request('title'),
            'owner_id' => request('owner_id')
        ]);

        Mail::to($project->owner->email)->send(
            new ProjectCreated($project)
        );

        return redirect('/projects');
    }
```

EDIT 2

Instead of using create method, try this one

```
public function store()
{
        $project = new Project();
        $project->title = request('title');
        $project->owner_id = request('owner_id');
        $project->save();
...
}
```

Comment: Class App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController does not exist      the name of my controller is ProjectsController

Comment: Yes replace ProjectController to ProjectsController

Comment: Strange. You got the same error after using request('title')?

Comment: i also have done php artisan migrate:fresh but actually the problem is in controller,,, m following the laracasts series and there he changes a lot code and i think i make any problem during shorten the code because initially it was working but after some changing its not working i have matched the code twice with that video but same error

Comment: can you please post the screenshot of dd($attributes);. It seems to be a problem with the $attributes value. dd() just above create function is called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195715/discussion-between-lizeshakya-and-programmer0001).

Comment: 404
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.